# How to achieve default value if column value is NULL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to retrieve some column values from table with these conditions.

- If value is NULL (or) Empty String , return some user defined value
- If not above condition , return it's value.

How can I figure it out ?

Here is my Table query..

```
CREATE TABLE AUCTION_CAR_BID(
bid_seq bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
auction_car_seq bigint NOT NULL,
bid_group_seq bigint NOT NULL,
bid_price int DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
over_bid_price int DEFAULT -1 NOT NULL,
result_id int DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
remark varchar(500),
PRIMARY KEY (bid_seq)) 
ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Here is my efforted codes to get it..

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(OVER_BID_PRICE, -1)
FROM
    AUCTION_CAR_BID
WHERE
    BID_SEQ = 2354435345;
```

**Another :**

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN OVER_BID_PRICE IS NULL
        OR TRIM(OVER_BID_PRICE) = '' THEN -1
        ELSE OVER_BID_PRICE
    END OVER_BID_PRICE
FROM
    AUCTION_CAR_BID
WHERE
    BID_SEQ = 2354435345;
```

But I always get empty String value(not -1) if given **id** is not in my table.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated !

Comment: Did you try this: `CASE WHEN (price IS NULL OR price = '')`

Comment: @Strawberry I had already tested with ifnull , coalesce , is null , null if. But still trouble or may be I am wrong.

Comment: @Aziz Shaikh , No still get empty string with id that not in my table! If id value is valid , i get it's result.

Comment: @Aziz Shaikh I also supprised on it , I thought that may satasfy but really.... I am sure with my table's records. No no no.. still return empty string value. If possible , I want to show with screen shots.

Comment: How can price be a string? You have some serious problem here.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull

Comment: Pls, no pictures, just text. BTW, you can use (for instance) MS OneNote to convert from to the other

Comment: @Strawberry , sorry ! :). Now converted to String . Thanks

Comment: @Cataclysm: Dear, if user_seq = 2354435345 no returns row you'll have NULL in this case you must put COALESCE out of the select. Your coalesce works only if you have a NULL value in the row returned by your where condition

Comment: @Joe Taras: I don't understand what you say . For give me , I am still a noob (beginner ) in it. Please guid me patiently . I would appreciate yours. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you write this:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(OVER_BID_PRICE, -1)
FROM
    AUCTION_CAR_BID
WHERE
    BID_SEQ = 2354435345;
```

The results can be two types.

First result: Your query no returns rows! Your WHERE condition is unsatisfact so you'll read NULL

Second result: Your query returns rows but the value of your field is NULL, your COALESCE works fine in this case

To resolve you can try this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(
   (SELECT
   COALESCE(OVER_BID_PRICE, -1)
   FROM AUCTION_CAR_BID
   WHERE BID_SEQ = 2354435345)
,-1);
```

Tell me if it's OK

Comment: Absolutely , Now I got it. Thank you very much . Have a nice day. I am so happy because of you.

Comment: @Cataclysm: Have a nice day you too ;)

Comment: @Cataclysm: Hi, if you put COALESCE without second parameter is a non sense. Please change your edit

Comment: Oh! really sir ? I am fine with this **SELECT COALESCE((SELECT OVER_BID_PRICE FROM AUCTION_CAR_BID WHERE BID_SEQ = 24234234), -1)**

Comment: @Cataclysm: OK, you can remove internal COALESCE ;)

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
select
case when price is null or id <> 1
then -1
else price
end price
from mytable
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DROP TABLE prices;

CREATE TABLE prices (price_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,price INT NULL);

INSERT INTO prices (price) VALUES (' '),(''),(NULL);

SELECT * FROM prices;
+----------+-------+
| price_id | price |
+----------+-------+
|        1 |     0 |
|        2 |     0 |
|        3 |  NULL |
+----------+-------+

SELECT price_id,COALESCE(price,-1) price FROM prices;
+----------+-------+
| price_id | price |
+----------+-------+
|        1 |     0 |
|        2 |     0 |
|        3 |    -1 |
+----------+-------+
```

Comment: my table structure is **price int DEFAULT -1 NOT NULL,**

Comment: **SELECT * FROM mytable;** also return **-1** ;

Comment: how to substitude **COALESCE** in my sql ?

Comment: Hang on. price is INT NOT NULL DEFAULT -1?!?!? So what's the problem? price is NEVER NULL (except in an outer join query)

Comment: Hm, there is something weird here.

Comment: thanks bro.. I will update my question with my fully table design and my query.

Comment: Now , I edited my question , previous is sample (for easy to understand)

Answer (score 2):

If there's no row for USER_SEQ = 2354435345 in your table there's no row returned. But aggregate functions always return a row even if the result is empty :-)

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(MIN(OVER_BID_PRICE), -1)
FROM
    USER_PARAM
WHERE
    USER_SEQ = 2354435345;
```

Comment: Yes , you are right. It also work :)  thanks for your useful knowledge.