# Unexpected behaviour INT NOT NULL DEFAULT -1

Tags: mysql

I rarely work with negative numbers (except personal finances) so perhaps that's why there's a gap in my knowledge here...

Consider the following, prompted by a response to a question asked by another user in SO ([How to achieve default value if column value is NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20701294/how-to-achieve-default-value-if-column-value-is-null/20701663?noredirect=1#comment31006687_20701663)):

```
-- Mysql Version 5.5.16
-- sql_mode = ''

DROP TABLE prices;

CREATE TABLE prices (price_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,price INT SIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT -1);

INSERT INTO prices (price) VALUES (' '),(''),(NULL);
INSERT INTO prices (price_id) VALUES (NULL);

SELECT * FROM prices;

Expected output:
+----------+-------+
| price_id | price |
+----------+-------+
|        1 |    -1 | 
|        2 |    -1 | 
|        3 |    -1 |
|        4 |    -1 |
+----------+-------+

Actual output:
+----------+-------+
| price_id | price |
+----------+-------+
|        1 |     0 |
|        2 |     0 |
|        3 |     0 |
|        4 |    -1 |
+----------+-------+
```

Why?

Intermediate answer: In a nutshell, it seems that if you want to be sure of inserting the default value (when sql_mode is not set), *either* omit the column from the INSERT *or* explicitly INSERT a DEFAULT value, i.e.: `INSERT INTO prices (price) VALUES(DEFAULT);` To me, this goes against the spirit of a DEFAULT value !?!?

Comment: With which version did you test it? Can't verify it with http://sqlfiddle.com Neither with 5.5 nor with 5.6. Your first insert statement fails for all 3 values.

Comment: 5.5.16, sql_mode = '', not strict_all_tables. This doesn't match my interpretation of the manual (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/constraint-invalid-data.html)

Comment: So Aziz and Alfabravo, you're both satisfied that this IS expected behaviour?

Comment: I think it is expected behavior when sql_mode is NOT strict.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like:

a.) If you provide a NULL value to a not null numeric field (not autoincrementing), the default is zero.

b.) If you dont provide a value (as in the last row), you use the given default value (-1)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html

Comment: I've read that page. While it suggests that pre 5.0.2 it behaved exactly as I would expect, I don't think it's clear on this specific point (post 5.0.2), except by inference. Am I missing something?

Comment: Indeed, there's a small gap in docs, this particular case is not explained. Also, agree with Aziz

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Mysql STRICT MODE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html) then the result could be different.

Currently you are providing a value `NULL`, the server tries to map this value to the closest INT value. The server is not using the default value of -1 because it is taking NULL as a valid value.